# What do I get 'Unknown key for this start object' error with runtime_mappings on elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to run an elasticsearch search using the elasticsearch package (v7.15) in python.
Below is the dict sent to the search function :

```json
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "tag_dynamic": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": {
        "source": """
        String nowString = params['now'];
        ZonedDateTime nowZdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(nowString);
        long now = nowZdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();

        ZonedDateTime mtimeZdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(doc['m_time']);
        long millisDateTime = mtimeZdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
        long Mtime_elapsedTime = now - millisDateTime;

        ZonedDateTime zdtMinus = nowZdt.minusDays(30);
        long millisMinusTime = zdtMinus.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
        long Mtime_elapsedTime = now - millisMinusTime;

        if (Mtime_elapsedTime > 3d0_elapsedTime) {
             dyntag = 'TOARCHIVE';}
        emit(dyntag);
        """,
        "params": {
          "now": "<generated string datetime in ISO-8601>"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "m_time:*"
    }
  }
}
```

And I get this error : `Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [runtime_mappings].` Yet the search syntax is nearly identitical to the one in the Elasticsearch docs.

Can anyone tell me the reason why I keep getting this error ?

I tested many variations , including removing the "query" part, adding "body":{ in the beginning, adding "query":{ in the beginning, etc. And I always get the same error.

Comment: which version of elasticsearch are you running ?

Comment: It turned out that my Elasticsearch clusters were running on an older version (7.10.2) and not 7.15, and are therefore too old to run runtime_mappings. Thanks for your help.